# Throw exception when update android support dependencies: RuntimeException: Unable to bind views for

Tags: android, android-support-library, runtimeexception, butterknife

I'm developing an app that uses:

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
```

My code **works correctly** with the following dependencies (**23.0.1**):

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
```

I want to **update** to (**23.1.0**):

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
```

**Note:** If android studio gives me an exception, before Sync Gradle I go to following menu

> Menu/build/Clean Project

**Error**: When run app on device this gives the following exception:

```
10-25 20:08:39.056 1817-1817/com.perdidos.syp.objetosperdidos E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-25 20:08:39.056 1817-1817/com.perdidos.syp.objetosperdidos E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.perdidos.syp.objetosperdidos/com.perdidos.syp.objetosperdidos.DrawerBaseActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to bind views for com.perdidos.syp.objetosperdidos.DrawerBaseActivity
10-25 20:08:39.056 1817-1817/com.perdidos.syp.objetosperdidos E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2351)
10-25 20:08:39.056 1817-1817/com.perdidos.syp.objetosperdidos E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403)
10-25 20:08:39.056 1817-1817/com.perdidos.syp.objetosperdidos E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:165)
10-25 20:08:39.056 1817-1817/com.perdidos.syp.objetosperdidos E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1373)
10-25 20:08:39.056 1817-1817/com.perdidos.syp.objetosperdidos E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
10-25 20:08:39.056 1817-1817/com.perdidos.syp.objetosperdidos E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
10-25 20:08:39.056 1817-1817/com.perdidos.syp.objetosperdidos E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5370)
10-25 20:08:39.056 1817-1817/com.perdidos.syp.objetosperdidos E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-25 20:08:39.056 1817-1817/com.perdidos.syp.objetosperdidos E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-25 20:08:39.056 1817-1817/com.perdidos.syp.objetosperdidos E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
10-25 20:08:39.056 1817-1817/com.perdidos.syp.objetosperdidos E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
10-25 20:08:39.056 1817-1817/com.perdidos.syp.objetosperdidos E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-25 20:08:39.056 1817-1817/com.perdidos.syp.objetosperdidos E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to bind views for com.perdidos.syp.objetosperdidos.DrawerBaseActivity
10-25 20:08:39.056 1817-1817/com.perdidos.syp.objetosperdidos E/AndroidRuntime:     at butterknife.ButterKnife.bind(ButterKnife.java:322)
10-25 20:08:39.056 1817-1817/com.perdidos.syp.objetosperdidos E/AndroidRuntime:     at butterknife.ButterKnife.bind(ButterKnife.java:237)
10-25 20:08:39.056 1817-1817/com.perdidos.syp.objetosperdidos E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.perdidos.syp.objetosperdidos.DrawerBaseActivity.onCreate(DrawerBaseActivity.java:131)
10-25 20:08:39.056 1817-1817/com.perdidos.syp.objetosperdidos E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
10-25 20:08:39.056 1817-1817/com.perdidos.syp.objetosperdidos E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1150)
10-25 20:08:39.056 1817-1817/com.perdidos.syp.objetosperdidos E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2315)
10-25 20:08:39.056 1817-1817/com.perdidos.syp.objetosperdidos E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403) 
10-25 20:08:39.056 1817-1817/com.perdidos.syp.objetosperdidos E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:165) 
10-25 20:08:39.056 1817-1817/com.perdidos.syp.objetosperdidos E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1373) 
10-25 20:08:39.056 1817-1817/com.perdidos.syp.objetosperdidos E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
10-25 20:08:39.056 1817-1817/com.perdidos.syp.objetosperdidos E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
10-25 20:08:39.056 1817-1817/com.perdidos.syp.objetosperdidos E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5370) 
10-25 20:08:39.056 1817-1817/com.perdidos.syp.objetosperdidos E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
10-25 20:08:39.056 1817-1817/com.perdidos.syp.objetosperdidos E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
10-25 20:08:39.056 1817-1817/com.perdidos.syp.objetosperdidos E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833) 
10-25 20:08:39.056 1817-1817/com.perdidos.syp.objetosperdidos E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600) 
10-25 20:08:39.056 1817-1817/com.perdidos.syp.objetosperdidos E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
10-25 20:08:39.056 1817-1817/com.perdidos.syp.objetosperdidos E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Required view 'imageCover' with ID 2131689711 for field 'mImageCover' was not found. If this view is optional add '@Nullable' annotation.
10-25 20:08:39.056 1817-1817/com.perdidos.syp.objetosperdidos E/AndroidRuntime:     at butterknife.ButterKnife$Finder.findRequiredView(ButterKnife.java:140)
10-25 20:08:39.056 1817-1817/com.perdidos.syp.objetosperdidos E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.perdidos.syp.objetosperdidos.DrawerBaseActivity$$ViewBinder.bind(DrawerBaseActivity$$ViewBinder.java:18)
10-25 20:08:39.056 1817-1817/com.perdidos.syp.objetosperdidos E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.perdidos.syp.objetosperdidos.DrawerBaseActivity$$ViewBinder.bind(DrawerBaseActivity$$ViewBinder.java:9)
10-25 20:08:39.056 1817-1817/com.perdidos.syp.objetosperdidos E/AndroidRuntime:     at butterknife.ButterKnife.bind(ButterKnife.java:319)
10-25 20:08:39.056 1817-1817/com.perdidos.syp.objetosperdidos E/AndroidRuntime:     at butterknife.ButterKnife.bind(ButterKnife.java:237) 
10-25 20:08:39.056 1817-1817/com.perdidos.syp.objetosperdidos E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.perdidos.syp.objetosperdidos.DrawerBaseActivity.onCreate(DrawerBaseActivity.java:131) 
10-25 20:08:39.056 1817-1817/com.perdidos.syp.objetosperdidos E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122) 
10-25 20:08:39.056 1817-1817/com.perdidos.syp.objetosperdidos E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1150) 
10-25 20:08:39.056 1817-1817/com.perdidos.syp.objetosperdidos E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2315) 
10-25 20:08:39.056 1817-1817/com.perdidos.syp.objetosperdidos E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403) 
10-25 20:08:39.056 1817-1817/com.perdidos.syp.objetosperdidos E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:165) 
10-25 20:08:39.056 1817-1817/com.perdidos.syp.objetosperdidos E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1373) 
10-25 20:08:39.056 1817-1817/com.perdidos.syp.objetosperdidos E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
10-25 20:08:39.056 1817-1817/com.perdidos.syp.objetosperdidos E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
10-25 20:08:39.056 1817-1817/com.perdidos.syp.objetosperdidos E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5370) 
10-25 20:08:39.056 1817-1817/com.perdidos.syp.objetosperdidos E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
10-25 20:08:39.056 1817-1817/com.perdidos.syp.objetosperdidos E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
10-25 20:08:39.056 1817-1817/com.perdidos.syp.objetosperdidos E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833) 
10-25 20:08:39.056 1817-1817/com.perdidos.syp.objetosperdidos E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600) 
10-25 20:08:39.056 1817-1817/com.perdidos.syp.objetosperdidos E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Question**: Do I have to wait for the library is updated butterknife?

Comment: I recommend that you post the entire stack trace.

Comment: I've attached the entire stack trace

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Required view 'imageCover' with ID 2131689711 for field 'mImageCover' was not found. If this view is optional add '@Nullable' annotation.` -- you may wish to provide more details about this `View` and field, to help us understand why Butterknife is not finding it.

Comment: I am using navigationView. ImageView is on nav_header.xml (simple imageview). Set on navigationView who: app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"